# Google SDK User Agent Issue on Linkedin iOS App

Tags: authorization, linkedin-api, google-signin, linkedin-jsapi

When our users try to navigate from a post from Linkedin App to a webview which opens our website, when they sign in using Google; Google SDK gives an Error:

> "Access Blocked: Authorization Error" (Error code 403: disallowed_useragent)

This case only happens when any of our users use the LinkedIn iOS app and click on our event link. If they copy the link and try another browser from their phone, the issue not occurs.